# Symfony validation_groups how to get entity value

Tags: php, symfony, oop, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

In Symfony I want to validate a form dynamically. Depending on a value of an entity field I want to enable an validation group, in the case named "payed". I use the following code:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
     $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Account',
        'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form) {

            // Set always default
            $valarr = ['Default'];

            $business = $form->get('business')->getData();
            if($business == true) $valarr[] = "business";

            // This needs to be added in pending on entity field value
            if(???) $valarr[] = "payed";

            return $valarr;
        },
    ));
}
```

How can I get my entity that is know in the controller where this form is activated into this function? For business it works as I can get the value from the form directly.

Comment: the method  $form->getData() should return the object Account can you make a try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Matteo says in the comment, you can just use `$form->getData()->$fieldname` to obtain the value.

```
if ($form->getData()->$fieldname === 'my_special_value') {
    $valarr[] = "payed";
}
```